# SQL Server FORXML Clause

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query in sql server

```
select a.*,b.first_loss_calc_result as "@firstLoss"
    from tablea a
    inner join tableb fl on b.id = a.ID
    FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('Response')
```

The response that i get back is the following format .

```
 <Response>
      <a  column1="test" column 2="testh"                  ">
        <b firstLoss="1.890600000000000e+001" />
      </a>
    </Response>
```

But i was looking out for a response format mentioned below :

```
 <Response>
    <a  column1="test" column 2="testh"     firstLoss= "1.890600000000000e+001"></a>         
  </Response>
```

Basically i want all the column from table a and single column from table B as an attribute to a element

Can someone let me know as how can i do that.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE (ID INT, column1 VARCHAR(100), Column2 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE1 VALUES 
(1, 'Col1 Value1', 'Col2 Value1'),
(2, 'Col1 Value2', 'Col2 Value2')


DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE (ID INT, FirstLoss INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 VALUES 
(1, 1000),(2,2000)
```

### Query

```
select A.column1   AS [@Column1]
      ,A.Column2   AS [@Column2]
      ,B.FirstLoss AS [@firstLoss]
from @TABLE1 a
inner join @TABLE2 B on b.id = a.ID
FOR XML PATH('a'), ROOT('Response')
```

### Result

```
<Response>
  <a Column1="Col1 Value1" Column2="Col2 Value1" firstLoss="1000" />
  <a Column1="Col1 Value2" Column2="Col2 Value2" firstLoss="2000" />
</Response>
```

Comment: is there a way to a.* on the first table in this query since the columns in table a are about 10-20 and keeps on changing

Comment: I thought the `AS [@Name]` was odd but turns out its necessary (or at least has an effect) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20004 vs. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20005

Comment: If you want values from columns to show as attribute values in XML you will need to use the column names along with alias starting with `@` this is by syntax there isnt a way around to this.